# Sharing control templates between different button types

Tags: wpf

I want to define a style for `ButtonBase` and then extend that style in different ways for `Togglebutton` and `Button`. I want something like this:

```
<!-- Base Style -->
<Style x:Key="ButtonBaseStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Style.Resources>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="NormalStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">...</ControlTemplate>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="HoverStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">...</ControlTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HoverStyle}" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NormalStyle}" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style> 

<!-- Toggle Button -->
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="ButtonBaseStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
       <ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckedStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">...</ControlTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <!-- ToggleButton should inherit the triggers defined in ButtonBaseStyle; adding the additional trigger specific to ToggleButton here -->
      <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CheckedStyle}" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

The style declaration for `ToggleButton` is wrong. `WPF` does not allow styles to inherit like that. I want to know if I can achieve this effect in any other way. Note that I am aware that I can make the control templates global and use them selectively for different button classes. That is what I am doing now but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the proposed way works, you just have one syntax error.

Replace:

```
BasedOn="ButtonBaseStyle"
```

With:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonBaseStyle}"
```